# user account of a website

Tags: iphone

I have 2 apps which realize different functions for accessing a same website.
I hope I input the account name and password in one app then store somewhere, when I use another app access the same website, it will recognize the stored account info and log in automatically.
Is it possible?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at UIPasteboard.  Useful for passing data between apps, but I don't know if it is secure enough for your particular application.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for your prompt anwser. But if user use UIPasteboard in another app between the 2 apps, the stored data info I think will be lost. I mean that if iPhone provides the mechanism to store some username and password permenantly or for a short time(1 month etc)?

Comment: I think it's OK.  Set the persistable flag to YES, and:

"A persistent application pasteboard is removed when the owning application is uninstalled."